# Using JSFL to change from one set of fonts to another (Flash 5)

Tags: flash-cs5, jsfl

I am trying to change from using one set of fonts to another using JFSL. The problem I am having is that I can't get or set the style of font (shown in the image below)

http://i39.tinypic.com/20pbnsg.png

For family: ITC Kabel Std
style: Bold

textField.getTextAttr("face"), I get ITC Kabel Std Medium.

Is there anyway to do this with JFSL? If not, what alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in flash, "bold" is most often a separate attribute form "face".

```
textField.setTextAttr("face","ITC Kabel Std")
textField.setTextAttr("bold",true)
```

it can be bold in flash but still the original font when evaluated.